# Nuxt 3 Apollo requests

Tags: javascript, nuxtjs3, penetration-testing

I’m building a nuxt application that consumes a headless CMS. Obviously each page after the first page render sends a GET requests for the the page data and there are 3 or 4 forms that send a POST.

I’m pretty new to pen testing but what the most common headers be in my get and post requests to make they as secure as possible?